# Highlighting a field in a table and have it print

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to yellow highlight a field in table and also have the yellow color print? This hightlights on the screen, but does not print the yellow:
`<td style="background-color: yellow">Total:</td>`

I found out that browsers, by design, do not print background colors. The only workaround I was able to find is that you can make a ultra-thick border of the cell or div:
`<td style="border-left: 999px solid yellow">`

Unfortunately, the cell contents won't overlay over the thick yellow border. I checked everywhere online and the closest answer I could find was on stack overflow:
[Best Ways to Get Around CSS Backgrounds Not Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468008/best-ways-to-get-around-css-backgrounds-not-printing)

However, the answer was untested and I was unable to get it working on my computer. I tried toying around and experimenting with no luck.

Comment: Make a print stylesheet.

Comment: You might find a lot of people passing on answering your questions if you don't accept more - 20% is not a nice number...

Comment: I was unaware of this. Thanks. Will answer more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution to my problem, but the solution is rather inelegant. Like I said in my above question, you have create a div tag with a big color border on it. The thing is is that colored borders can print correctly. Then, where the highlighted color is displayed, lay another div tag with the text on top. Inelegant, but it works.

It's best to set both the text div and the highlight div's within a third "outer" div for easy placement. the inner divs should be position "absolute" and the outer div should have position "relative". Sample code is below. This is tested code on both Chrome and Firefox:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #outer_box {
      position: relative; 
      border: 2px solid black; 
      width: 500px; 
      height:300px; 
  }

  #yellow_highlight {
      position: absolute; 
      width: 0px;
      height: 30px;
      border-left: 300px;
      border-color: yellow; 
      border-style: solid; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0px
  }


  #message_text {
      position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="outer_box">
    <div id="yellow_highlight">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="message_text">hello, world!</div>
  </div>
</body>
```